# LAN to WIFI Adaptor

Tags: router

is there a device which converts the incoming lan signals into wifi signals?

The apartment only has a fixed network ip with a predetermined gateway and DNS. One needs to give this static ip, netmask and gateway in the network configuration of the computer and it works.

But I would like to use smart phones to access the network. Hence the static settings should be done in the device ( maybe it is  is called an lan to wifi adaptor  ) itself . Ofcourse, I do not want an expensive ADSL or DSL because I do not need the modem functionality.

Also, it would be great to know how this network device works i.e how does it give the IP addresses to the connected devices - may be using NAT?

Help with links what I should look for, would be appreciated.

Edit 05 June, 2017:

I have a FritzBox 7240, which according to this manual ( German ) https://avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7240/wissensdatenbank/publication/show/106_FRITZ-Box-fuer-Betrieb-mit-anderem-Router-einrichten/, should be able to fulfill my needs. But the problem there is, that the static IP provided by the external router is class B ( 134.x.x.x ). If I enter this static IP into the FritzBox's Routers configuration and activate the DHCP server of the Fritzbox to provide IPs ( Class C - 192.168.178.x ) that would distribute the IP's to the connected devices, the Fritz box complains a conflict between the Class B incoming IP and the class C Fritzbox's DHCP IP.

So, I have left with no other choice, but to buy some other device like an Access Point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point

Comment: @goldilocks can you suggest some links to buy. I need to put static ip , dns and gateway in the access point. I tried with Fritzbox 7240, but does not work. Maybe Fritzbox 7240 cannot be used as an access point.

Comment: An Access Point will basically translate wifi to lan signals and vice versa. If you want to use more than one device behind this one static IP, you want a proper _router_, which will route from your subnet to the "more public network". If you do not need to run more than one device at any time, a "simple" access point will work. So now for the obligatory questions: How much money are you willing to spend? What else beyond the above explained functionality do you want / need?

Comment: I'm going to contradict @SEJPM on this point (as does wikipedia: *"One IEEE 802.11 AP can typically communicate with 30 client systems located within a radius of 103 metres..."*).   AP's work by using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) with a private subnet.  This does mean the client devices are effectively hidden from the LAN, but that only matters if they are running IP servers, or you want zeroconf/mDNS stuff to work across the AP -- but a complete router is not a transparent solution to that either (unless you move everything but your ISP router onto it).

Comment: @SEJPM Just normal internet connectivity. I am not hosting any server and neither I want any specific ports like ssh, http/s etc to be running. Budget - cheaper the better.

Comment: @goldilocks Is FritzBox 7240 an AP or a Router? As far as I understand, the router is only advantageous if one is running an active server, otherwise a normal AP should work. I still could not find any Access Points in internet to buy.

Comment: If you are German, here should be an [AVM help article](https://avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7240/wissensdatenbank/publication/show/106_FRITZ-Box-fuer-Betrieb-mit-anderem-Router-einrichten/) on your situation. What a router does, is to forward packets between subnets and separating them (with the firewall as well). Actual dedicated access points are mostly an enterprise phenomen (like [ubiquiti unifi ones](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#unifi)) but most routers can be configured to act as one.

Comment: If your intention is to setup static IPs on a dynamic network, you could just configure your devices to always request the same IP address via DHCP make your devices essentially static.

Comment: @SEJPM the AVM help article does not work. The problem is that the static IP provided by the router is class B ( 134.x.x.x ) and if I enter it into the routers configuration and activate the DHCP server ( Class C - 192.168.178.x ) of the router to provide IPs to the connected devices, the fritz box complains a conflict between the Class B incoming IP and the class C Router DHCP IP.

Comment: I _think_ there are some miss-conceptions about networking and router configuration going on here. I'd suggest you ask on [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/) for advice. For example modern networks have long left the class-based approach to IP adresses behind.

Comment: I am going to give up the fritz box router and buy a simple Wifi Access point like this .  http://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/TL-WA901ND_4.0.pdf. I hope it will work. Thank you for the answers anyways.

Comment: If you've already got a working wired network, you want a "bridge" rather than an "access point" or a "router".

Comment: @Mark there is only one ethernet cable coming out of the wall and I connect it to my computer. In the computer, I configure the eth0 with a  static IP, dns and gateway provided to me by the owner of the apartment. Hence, I dont have a working wired network. Just one computer connected. I would like to have a wireless network though. Can you recommend me a hardware with a weblink? The hardware should be configurable though, so that I configure the hardware with the static ip, dns and gateway.

Comment: Found this cheap device which acts as a bridge, AP, router - all in one and is configurable with static ip, dns and gateway - http://www.edimax.com/edimax/mw/cufiles/files/download/manual/BR-6428NS_V4/BR-6428nS_V4_User_Manual_English_EN.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this cheap device which acts as a bridge, AP, router - all in one and is configurable with static ip, dns and gateway -

http://www.edimax.com/edimax/mw/cufiles/files/download/manual/BR-6428NS_V4/BR-6428nS_V4_User_Manual_English_EN.pdf